# Issue in upgrading User Profile Service from SP2013 to SP2016

Tags: user-profile, migration, upgrade, user-profile-property, user-profile-service-app

I'm trying to upgrade the User profile service from a SP2013 to SP2016. The 2013 farm uses the "Sharepoint Profile Synchronization" option - set in the "Configure Synchronization Settings" page. We have a number of custom AD properties mapped to user profile properties and this is the data that I am looking to keep when I upgrade to SP2016.

When I upgrade the UPS by moving the SQL DBs from 2013 to 2016 and create the UPS via script specifying the DB names I can see the profiles and I can see the custom properties in the user profiles but the mapping is gone.

The synchronization connection did not come over and had to be recreated using "Use SharePoint Active Directory Import".Now,when I edit a user property to set a mapping,there is no "Property mapping for Synchronization" and I can't add one - I'm unable to select an attribute.

The image below is I'm trying to map an attribute to a user property but no attributes gets displayed in the drop down.

Please note: I'm used "Active Directory Import" when I created user profile synchronization connection

I expect this to be a known issue.Can someone help me with a fix or workaround?

[image]

Comment: For AD Sync you need to type the property name manually in the "Attribute" text box, not select it from the empty dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were previously using FIM for sync you will have to change your process in 2016. In 2016 you can either use Active Directory Import, which is limited, very limited. Alternatively you can use a third party import like MIM or just write your own in PowerShell.